# Rails angularjs convert to erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to include angularjs in my code

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="editUser(user.id)">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  Edit
        </button>
```

So here is the code I need to convert in  erb

```
<%= button_to , :class => 'btn'  do %>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  Edit
        <% end %>
```

how to write this ng-click="editUser(user.id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`button_to` creates a form tag, which is by far an overkill here, also note that `button_to` requires a url and will attach some extra javascript listeners on it. Just use pure html:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="editUser(user.id)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  Edit
</button>
```

If you really prefer erb in some form, use `content_tag`:

```
<%= content_tag :button, class: 'btn', 'ng-click' => '(editUser(user.id)' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  Edit
<% end %>
```

I personally use haml for templates, as it plays very nicely with ng prefix. Many people complains that it makes large file harder to read - I think this is good as it forces you to have short files, for which readability is just great:

```
%button.btn{ng: {click: '(editUser(user.id)'}}
  %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil
  Edit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
<%= button_to , :class => 'btn',  "ng-click" => "editUser(#{user.id})" do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  Edit
<% end %>
```